# invalid type argument of -> have struct room

Tags: c

Alright Here is my situation. I need to use pointers for my room struct but for some reason its saying -> is a invalid type. When i was the dot, it works. The thing is AllRooms is a pointer so shouldn't it be -> to modify the elements in the struct. What do i need to change so i can use the -> instead of the dot. Or with my situation its better to use the dot?

```
struct room
{
   int roomNum;
   int creaturesTotal;
   int roomStatus;
   int roomTotal;
   int north;
   int south;
   int east;
   int west;
};



int main
{

    int numberofrooms = 0;

    *ask user for rooms and creatures*/
    printf("How many rooms? Max 100 rooms: ");
    scanf("%d",&numberofrooms);

    /*make sure its under 10 rooms*/
    while(numberofrooms > 100)
    {
       printf("\nToo many rooms!\n");
       printf("How many rooms? Max 100 rooms: ");
       scanf("%d",&numberofrooms);
    }

  struct Creatures* AllCreatures = malloc(numberofcreatures * sizeof(numberofcreatures));

  createRooms(numberofrooms, AllRooms);

}



void createRooms(int numberofrooms,struct room* AllRooms)
{
int counter = 0;
int status;
int north;
int south;
int east;
int west;

//ask the user for the cords
for(int i =0; i < numberofrooms;i++)
{
    printf("Room Number %d state north south east west: ",counter);
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&status,&north,&south,&east,&west);
    AllRooms[i]->roomStatus = status;
    AllRooms[i]->north = north;
    AllRooms[i]->south = south;
    AllRooms[i]->east = east;
    AllRooms[i]->west = west;
    AllRooms[i]->roomNum = counter;
    AllRooms[i]->roomTotal = 0;
    counter++;
}

//print out the cords
for(int i =0; i < numberofrooms;i++)
{
    printf("\n%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",AllRooms[i].roomStatus,AllRooms[i].north,AllRooms[i].south,AllRooms[i].east,AllRooms[i].west);
}
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: All of the lines that has the -> operator

Comment: Suspicious allocation, suggest `AllCreatures = malloc(numberofcreatures * sizeof(numberofcreatures));` --> `AllCreatures = malloc(sizeof *AllCreatures * numberofcreatures);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AllRooms[i]->roomStatus = status;
```

> The thing is AllRooms is a pointer so shouldn't it be -> to modify the elements in the struct.

You are correct that `AllRooms` is a pointer and you should use `->` with a pointer. But you aren't using `->` with `AllRooms` here. Looking closely at your code, you will see that the left side of the `->` operator is `AllRooms[i]`, not `AllRooms`. This is a struct, not a pointer, because you are indexing the pointer like an array. So you need to use the `.` operator instead:

```
AllRooms[i].roomStatus = status;
```

Comment: ok so the only thing that is a pointer is my array of structs, but the structs in my array aren't pointers

Comment: Thanks for the clarification tho

Comment: @NazarTrut Exactly. It is possible to make an array of pointers to structs, but that's not what you are doing here. You have an array of structs and a pointer to the first element in that array.

Comment: how would i create a array of pointers to structs? would i still use  the malloc function for that

Comment: @NazarTrut Pointers are not arrays. Your parameter `AllRooms` is a pointer to a single `struct room` object. The object it points to happens to be the initial element of an array. Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @NazarTrut Yes, when you have pointers of any kind, you often need to use `malloc()`. I suggest you keep reading and studying to figure out how to create an array of pointers.